# Java: how to convert dec to 32bit int?

Tags: java, double, decimal

How to convert decimal presentation of an ip address to 32bit integer value in java?
I use InetAddress class and getLocalHost method to obtain an IP adress:

```
public class getIp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   InetAddress ipaddress;

    try {
      ipaddress=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
       System.out.println(ipaddress);
        }
      catch(UnknownHostException ex)
      {
        System.out.println(ex.toString()); 
      }


    }
}
```

Than I should convert the result to 32bit integer value and than to string, how do I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos, double can hold IPv6 [and before you ask how would you use it: Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d)]. But it looks geekish to keep IP addr in double, does it not?

Comment: @bestsss: No, double (and long) have only 64 bits, IPv6 addresses have 128 bits each.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann, sure it is. You need more than a single double, it was supposed to be a joke; okie, didn't work well, i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IP address is IPv6, it won’t work. 
Otherwise for the Sun/Oracle implementation and IPv4, you can play dirty: 
`ipaddress.hashCode()`—*works but may break in the future, therefore not recommended*.

Otherwise (recommended): `int ipv4 = ByteBuffer.wrap(addr.getAddress()).getInt()`

Answer (score 5):

An IP address simply *isn't* a `double` value. It's like asking the number for the colour red. It doesn't make sense.

What are you *really* trying to do? What are you hoping to achieve? What's the bigger picture? Whatever it is, I don't think you want to get `double` involved.

Comment: Number of red: 0xFF0000 ;)

Comment: @The MYYN: That's one representation of it... but it's not a *universal* representation by any means. There's no *natural* number for red...

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to have ipv6 addresses, you should use long instead of integer.
You can convert the address into a single long shifting each byte into it.

```
long ipNumber = 0;
for (Byte aByte : ipaddress.getAddress()) {
    ipNumber = (ipNumber << 8) + aByte;
}
```

This will work for both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses.

Comment: `long` only stores 64 bits, IPv6 needs 128.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get it as a byte array instead?

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAddress%28%29

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong, but may be the man just wanted to pring hex ip address? ;)

Try this:

```
    try {
        InetAddress ipaddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println(ipaddress);

        byte[] bytes = ipaddress.getAddress();
        System.out.println(String.format("Hex address: %02x.%02x.%02x.%02x", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]));
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
```