# Querying Sql server with index for range

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, virtual-machine

I am using SQL SERVER 2012 that is running on windows datacenter 2012,

I have a database with a table that is build as followed :

```
[ID] (pk,int not null)
[Start] (float,null)
[End] (float, null)
[CID] (int,null) --country id
```

I have a web service that gets an IP, translate it to decimal 
(may refer to this : [IP address conversion to decimal and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130464/ip-address-conversion-to-decimal-and-vice-versa)) and request the database server for the country id

The table mentioned at first contains ~200K rows with start and end values representing IP ranges as decimal and a countryid related to each range,

I have encountered a really high CPU usage against some heavy traffic we have been dealing, so i added indexes on the start and end columns, afterwards the cpu got a little bit better but i think it should have been much more, its simply suppose to work as a search in a sorted list which should be extremely fast, though the expected result i had from adding the index were far from reality,

I suppose it is because its not searching a list but searching a range

What would be the best way to efficient this situation, since i am just sure that the resources this simple action is taking me is way to much than it should.

Here is a picture from the activity monitor now (lower traffic, after indexing) :
[image]

This is running on Azure ExtraLarge VM (8 cores 14GB memory) - the vm is doing nothing but running a sql server with 1 table that only translates this 1 request ! the VM CPU on this lower traffic is ~30% and ~70% on higher traffic, i am sure some structure/logical changes should make a really small server\service handle this easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM IP
WHERE StartIP <= yourIP
ORDER BY StartIP
```

This gets you the nearest IP range above the given IP. You then need to test whether the EndIP also matches. So:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT TOP 1 *
 FROM IP
 WHERE StartIP <= yourIP
 ORDER BY StartIP
) x
WHERE EndIP >= yourIP
```

This amounts to a single-row index seek. Perfect performance.

The reason SQL Server *cannot* automatically do this is that it cannot know that IP ranges are ordered, meaning that the next `StartIP` is always greater than the current `EndIP`. We could have ranges of the form `(100, 200), (150, 250)`. That is clearly invalid but it could be in the table.

Comment: It sould be SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT TOP 1 *
 FROM IP
 WHERE StartIP <= yourIP
 ORDER BY StartIP DESC
) x
WHERE EndIP >= yourIP

Comment: Might well be, not sure. Did you test that?

Comment: Tested the query to return same results, now testing the performance and than i will comment here :)

Answer (score 0):

In my **opinion** you main problem is the lack of "parameterization" because (a) query compilation is/can be expensive and (b) these "unparamterized" queries seems to have a lot of executions. And the available screenshot shows two things regarding this aspect:

1) The recent expensive queries aren't "parameterized".

2) High values for "Plan count":

> Plan Count The number of cached query plans for this query. A large
>   number might indicate a need for explicit query parameterization. For
>   more information, see Specifying Query Parameterization Behavior by
>   Using Plan Guides.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879320%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)

So, I would try to use parameters for these queries:

```
SELECT TOP(1) CountryId FROM [IP] WHERE Column1 <= @param AND @param <= Column2
```

If you can't change the application (how SQL requests are sended to SQL Server) then you could try plan guides:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms191275(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: That's going to perform an expensive index intersection. The index seeks will on average produce half of the table. That's his main problem.

Comment: Half ? Your know very well. If you real carefully, I'm not saying this is the only problem. But should be the first step and and most simple step.

Comment: On average half, yes. Everything greater than the given IP will be read. The IPs are kind of randomly distributed.